# Generic class with multiple types

Tags: c#, class, generics, generic-list

is this possible to create class with multiple not knowing types ? 
ex:
consider I have:

```
class MyClass <Type1, Type2, Type3, TResponse >
{

public TResponse Run()
{
     //operation on Type1, Type2, Type3
}


}
```

and my question is if this is possible to pass some how list of types and then use them in loop? and then wondering how to call it.

Comment: Pass *what* a list of types? Your question is very unclear at the moment. It would help if you could show how you'd expect to call the method, and what you'd expect the result to be.

Comment: If you have several classes with different types, implementing the same interface, would you be able to achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: WIth .Net 4 or newer, you can also use the `dynamic` keyword for "unknown" types. Would that be usable in your context (instead of generics)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can define a generic class with multiple types, the following code compiles. However in order to perform operations on those types you often need to define [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on the types.

```
public class MyClass <Type1, Type2, Type3, TResponse>
{
    public TResponse Run()
    {
        return default(TResponse);
    }
}
```

The generic types however are explicitly specified, AFAIK there is no way to specify a list of generic types that your class has.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible if all the classes expose same functionality either using interface or an abstract class. Once we have the base type, we can create generic class with multiple type parameters. Inside the generic class we can call any of the exposed functionality.